# Django Query : Compiling data with `seconds` difference in TimeField

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have the following model in my Django application :

```
class PeopleCount(models.Model):
    """
    A webapp model classs to store People Count Details.
    """
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    people_count_entry = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    people_count_exit = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=True, null=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera)
    recorded_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "People Count {}".format(self.timestamp)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "People Count"
        verbose_name_plural = "People Count"
        ordering = ['-recorded_time']
```

I want to print out the values of PeopleCount where if the difference between the time of enlisting of two objects is less than 1 seconds I can aggregate their values. For example:

- Let's say I get PeopleCountObjA -> at 11:30:21 (where people_count_entry was 4)
- And then I get another value PeopleCountObjB -> at 11:30:22(where people_Count_entry was 2)
- I should get answer as Group Count should be 6

  - The time 11:30:21 and 11:30:22 refers to recorded_time field from the model.

I tried using the aggregate query but unable to put in filter for delta difference of one second.

Hope I am clear with the question. TIA

Comment: Let me get this right, given a `PeopleCount` instance; you want to find the total (sum of) `people_count_entry` that were created (i.e. `timestamp`) within one second plus/minus that instance?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much.